# How to create EventSetter launching after animation

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I need to change properties of object after the animation ends.
I was happy when I read about 'Completed', but when I tried:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation 
     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
     To="RoyalBlue"
     Duration="0:0:1"
     Completed="ColorAnimation_Completed"/>
</Storyboard>
```

I got:

The event 'Completed' cannot be specified on a Target tag in a Style. Use an EventSetter instead.

How to create EventSetter in this case?

Answer (score 2):

if this is being set in a style, you can set your storyboard as a static resource to whatever control you're currently using:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
         <storyboard x:Key"Animation">
            <ColorAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
            To="RoyalBlue"
            Duration="0:0:1"
            Completed="ColorAnimation_Completed"/>
         </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then, on your control:

```
<Style x:Name="Style" TargetType="{x:Type yourcontroltype}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=whatevertriggeresyouranimation}" Value="triggerValue" >
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Animation}">
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
```

You need to fill in a few variables here because I don't see enough of what you are doing, but this will work.